# How to set up a route that matches any path by file extension

Tags: nancy

I want to have a route in NancyFX match an jpg path, regardless of the number of path segments.  For example, it should match all of:

- /image.jpg
- /foo/image.jpg
- /foo/bar/baz/foo/baz.jpg

Is this possible?  It seems all the wildcard options I find for NancyFX are for a particular path segment and do not allow multiple segments (where a segment is a portion separated by '/').

It seems like it should be possible, as the static content server would need to be able to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nancy supports regular expressions in routes. You can use a regular expression to match all the routes to `.jpg` images, and capture the path and name of the images:

```
public MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get[@"(?<imagepath>.*)/(?<imagename>.*.jpg)"] = 
            params => 
            {
                string path = params.imagepath;
                string name = params.imagename;
                return DoStuff(path, name);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we just use `@"(.*.jpg)"` for any image paths? like `/foo/bar/baz/foo/baz.jpg`

Comment: And this doesn't work for `/foo/bar/baz/foo/baz.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get[@"^(?<path>.*\.jpg)$"] = p => 
        {
            string path = p.path;
        }
    }
}
```

Result (path values):

- `image.jpg`
- `foo/image.jpg`
- `foo/bar/baz/foo/baz.jpg`